# Inconsistent login issues when connecting to a GoDaddy-based Microsoft 365 mailbox via Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook, godaddy

The circumstances:

- This is a personal machine, less than a year old, running windows 10 Home, fully updated.
- Office 2016, fully updated.
- There is a Microsoft account associated with the machine.
- Outlook 2016 configured to get mail from a GoDaddy-based Microsoft 365 mailbox.
- Mailbox password, MS account password, etc. are all the same, or were until GoDaddy’s tech support got involved.

The problem:

- When Outlook is opened, an authentication request comes up, with “Microsoft account{their MS account name}” populated in the user field.
- Occasionally, entering the password works and the mailbox opens, but usually not.
- Occasionally, replacing the user name with the mailbox account name and entering the password works, but usually not.
- Clearing ALL passwords from the credential manager usually works, but only for a day or two, then the problem comes back.
- GoDaddy and MS 365 people have tried to assist, but to no avail.

Has anyone seen something similar before?

Comment: I doubt anyone here can help you with something that in all likelihood is either a problem of saved/cached (wrong) authentication info or problems authenticating at the remote servers, when you say *GoDaddy and MS 365 people have tried to assist, but to no avail*.